# Java how to pass a thread an extra object

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I dont think this is possible, but I want to tell each of my threads to work on a specific object. Sorta like this -

```
class Tester implements Runnable{
    String s1, s2;
    Thread t1, t2;

    test(){
        t1 = new Thread(this, "t1");
        t2 = new Thread(this, "t2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        if(this is t1){
            s1="s1";
        }
        if(this is t2){
            s2="s2";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to somehow be able to tell `thread t1` to run code  on `string s1` and `t2` on `s2`. Right now I simply do it by checkiing `Thread.currentThreat.getName()`, but thats not a good way. The alternative would be to make an anonymous `Runnable` class that has its own string and just `run` on that, but then how does the main thread get both of the strings after?

Comment: Declare an interface `Worker` with a `public void doWork(String param)` method and pass `Worker` field in your class that implements the `Runnable`, then in `run` method use `worker.doWork`. Still, note that this can be easy if you use two different classes that implements `Runnable` interface though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not pass the different `Thread`s different `Runnable`s?

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() { public void run() { /* this is r1 */ } };
Runnable r2 = new Runnable() { public void run() { /* this is r2 */ } };
Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

/edit

Create a class you can instantiate:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String s;

    public MyRunnable(Stirng s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        // do something with s
    }
}

Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable("s1"));
Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable("s2"));
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

/e2

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ExecutorServiceExample {
    private static class CallableExample implements Callable<Integer> {
        private final Object foo;

        private CallableExample(Object foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer call() {
            // do something and return it
            return foo.hashCode();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Future<Integer> f1 = e.submit(new CallableExample("foo"));
        Future<Integer> f2 = e.submit(new CallableExample("bar"));

        System.out.println(f1.get());
        System.out.println(f2.get());

        e.shutdown();
    }
}
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)'s a good tutorial on the `Executor` framework.

Comment: I'de prefer to just have one run function (makes some other things easier), but this could be done.

Comment: @Dgrin91 Are the two `Thread`s doing basically the same thing except the `String` being used is different?

Comment: Yes, the exact same thing, just on a different instance of the same object.

Comment: But then how do I get the new `String` after the threads complete?

Comment: @Dgrin91 You could create a getter in your `Runnable`, but your problem is beginning to sound like a good candidate for using a [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) with an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). See my second edit.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest use of [Thread Local](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

you can visit the dummy examples from [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/threadlocal/) and [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-use-threadlocal-in-java-benefits.html)